# Android Restlet HTTPS - Communication Error (1001) - Error while processing a connection

Tags: android, google-app-engine, https, restlet

I'm trying to perform a get request with servlet but I get Communication Error (1001) - Error while processing a connection.

My code is quite simple:

```
    Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
    Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpsClientHelper(null));

    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(URI);
    cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
    cr.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, 
            SensorUpdaterApp.getInstance().GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, 
            SensorUpdaterApp.getInstance().GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN);
    DataTableResource resource = cr.wrap(DataTableResource.class);

    Long newId = null;
    try{
        newId = resource.createDataset();
    } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Here is the stacktrace I get in my logcat:

```
08-16 13:21:24.221: I/org.restlet(11223): Starting the internal [HTTPS/1.1] client
    08-16 13:21:24.311: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9361 objects / 434480 bytes in 59ms
    08-16 13:21:24.391: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 444 objects / 16384 bytes in 54ms
    08-16 13:21:24.471: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 505 objects / 18800 bytes in 53ms
    08-16 13:21:24.561: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 703 objects / 26368 bytes in 41ms
    08-16 13:21:24.631: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 870 objects / 32216 bytes in 41ms
    08-16 13:21:24.911: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 15029 objects / 968672 bytes in 46ms
    08-16 13:21:25.241: I/org.restlet(11223): A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
    08-16 13:21:25.731: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24605 objects / 1514848 bytes in 60ms
    08-16 13:21:27.531: I/org.restlet(11223): A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
    08-16 13:21:28.491: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 33569 objects / 1502352 bytes in 78ms
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223): Communication Error (1001) - Error while processing a connection
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:611)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:236)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at $Proxy5.createDataset(Native Method)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at com.sensorupdater2.activities.main.CreateNewDatasetAsyncTask.doInBackground(CreateNewDatasetAsyncTask.java:38)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at com.sensorupdater2.activities.main.CreateNewDatasetAsyncTask.doInBackground(CreateNewDatasetAsyncTask.java:1)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    08-16 13:21:29.821: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-16 13:21:29.831: W/System.err(11223):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientSessionContext$HostAndPort.hashCode(ClientSessionContext.java:214)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:393)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientSessionContext.putSession(ClientSessionContext.java:190)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientHandshakeImpl.unwrap(ClientHandshakeImpl.java:308)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLRecordProtocol.unwrap(SSLRecordProtocol.java:413)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:478)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:383)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.ReadableSslChannel.onDrain(ReadableSslChannel.java:114)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:553)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:668)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.ReadableBufferedChannel.read(ReadableBufferedChannel.java:172)
    08-16 13:21:29.841: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.fill(Buffer.java:391)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.InboundWay.onFill(InboundWay.java:278)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:597)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:668)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.processIoBuffer(Way.java:477)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.InboundWay.processIoBuffer(InboundWay.java:353)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.onSelected(Way.java:430)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.controlConnections(ConnectionController.java:105)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.doRun(ConnectionController.java:156)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at org.restlet.engine.connector.Controller.run(Controller.java:158)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    08-16 13:21:29.851: W/System.err(11223):    ... 5 more
    08-16 13:21:31.181: D/dalvikvm(11223): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 31659 objects / 1496144 bytes in 101ms
    08-16 13:21:31.181: I/org.restlet(11223): Stopping the internal[HTTPS/1.1] client
```

In my libs directory I have:

- gcm.jar
- org.restlet.ext.httpclient.jar - Probably unuseful
- org.restlet.ext.net.jar - Probably unuseful
- org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar
- org.restlet.jar

I tested the server with some other client and it seems to work

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the code works well without https

Comment: I suggest that you remove org.restlet.ext.httpclient.jar from your classpath and manually registers the org.restlet.ext.net.jar extension using this code: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html

Comment: Hi Jerome and thanks for your answer. I already tryed it (you can see the registration code on the top of the page) but it didn't work. I also tryed to use the newest (unstable) version of restlet. It doesn't show me any error, but the process never ends.

Answer (score 2):

I found that importing just the `org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper` made both HTTPS and HTTP work, so you might want to try that (but be careful - this behaviour changes depending which exact `HttpClientHelper` you import).

If you deliberately want to use `org.restlet.ext.ssl.HttpsClientHelper` then you will need to also import the org.jsslutils_1.0 library.  If you don't then the connection just times out forever (at least that's what I saw when testing with the Restlet 2.1.0 on Android).

The readme.txt in the Restlet 2.1.0 [download](http://www.restlet.org/downloads/) shows the dependencies for each of the JARs.  org.restlet.ext.ssl depends on jsslutils:

> org.restlet.ext.ssl (Restlet Extension - SSL)
>   - org.jsslutils_1.0

FYI, the Restlet download also includes all of the dependent libraries, so you can get them from there.

Here are some other miscellaneous things I found while testing this:

- Make sure you import and use the correct connector (when I imported the `HttpClientHelper Eclipse offered me 4 different ones).  The Restlet wiki Connectors page lists the server and client connectors available:
  http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/37-restlet.html
- When I tried the `org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper` I don't think I needed to import all its dependencies for my HTTP connector to work (possibly because I am only using the client side parts).
- Make sure all your JARs are from the same Restlet release, otherwise you could end up with weird errors.
- If you only import the `org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper` connector and not an HTTPS one you will see a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'https' not registered`.